# Doesn't Scikit learn need model initialization during looped training?

Tags: scikit-learn, initialization

While implementing K-fold using Scikit Learn in DecisionTreeClassifier model, I'm having hard time understanding why this baseline code doesn't contain any model initialization part. From my perspective, while fitting take place with iterations, the model which has already learned by first iteration stays the same(with identical parameter) during the second loop fitting and so on.

You can see my code below.
What I'm really curious about is, "Unlike other deep learning libraries like Pytorch etc, isn't there any need for model initialization for scikit-learn? or does this code below automatically do the initialization?(if so plz let me know where the parameter initialization take place)

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
cv_accuracy = []
n_iter = 0
kfold = KFold(n_splits = 5, random_state = None, shuffle = False)

for train_index, validation_index in kfold.split(train_data, train_label):
    x_train, x_val = train_data[train_index], train_data[validation_index]
    y_train, y_val = train_label[train_index], train_label[validation_index]

    train_size = x_train.shape[0]
    val_size = x_val.shape[0]

    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    pred = model.predict(x_val)
    n_iter += 1

    accuracy = np.round(accuracy_score(y_val, pred), 4)
    cv_accuracy.append(accuracy)

    # Thought I should initialize model somehow... in this part
    model = DecisionTreeClassifier()

print('\n## Accuracy : ', np.mean(cv_accuracy))
```

Answer (score 0):

`fit()` constructs a brand new tree behind the scenes (`DecisionTreeClassifierObj.tree_`), so it does that for you. The class init just provides the parameters it will use.

[Here's the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/15a949460/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L143) for that btw so you can see.

Simplified version of what `fit()` does:

```py
#Process data
self.tree_ = Tree(self.n_features_, self.n_classes_, self.n_outputs_)

builder = BestFirstTreeBuilder(splitter, min_samples_split, min_samples_leaf,
                               min_weight_leaf, max_depth, max_leaf_nodes,
                               self.min_impurity_decrease, min_impurity_split)

builder.build(self.tree_, X, y, sample_weight)

self._prune_tree()

return self
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Your answer was exactly what i was looking for!!! Just one more thing tho... what did you mean by 'class init'? I cant find any class named 'init' in the linked page of source code you've provided. Any comment would be a great help thanks again in advance

Comment: Meant the constructor, my bad. @gi3265